# ValidationException in AWS when creating a CA Certificate

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl

Well hello there. I have a problem when creating my CA certificate in my AWS.
I have download the `CSR.pem` file that the AWS site gives me. I send this file to my instance (is an ubuntu server). I followed the instructions to sign the file.

```
openssl genrsa 2048 > CRS.pem
```

This generated a file CSR.pem. Not quite sure why I needed to create this file but it was done. After that it said I had to:

```
openssl req -new -key CRS.pem -out CSR.pem
```

This worked and I had to put my credentials. Then it said that I had to create a new file the the days I need the certify.

```
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in CRS.pem -signkey CSR.pem -out server.crt
```

I got an error with this, and after looking around I found this solution.

```
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in CSR.pem -signkey key.pem -out server.crt
```

I exported back this 3 files.

```
CSR.pem
CRS.pem
key.pem
```

I thought that I had everything to get my CA certificate but when selecting the pem files I got this error:

> ValidationException 
>   1 validation error detected: Value '-----BEGIN
>   CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
>   MIIC1DCCAbwCAQAwgY4xCzAJBgNVBAYTAkVDMRIwEAYDVQQIDAlQaWNoaW5jaGEx
>   DjAMBgNVBAcMBVF1aXRvMQ8wDQYDVQQKDAZab2V0aXMxCzAJBgNVBAsMAklUMRUw
>   EwYDVQQDDAxEYXZpZCBadXJpdGExJjAkBgkqhkiG9w0BCQEWF2luZm9AY2VyYmVy
>   dXNsYWJzLmdhbWVzMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA+pYW
>   xjny8rPfO4/sWmlWfWfMgZBwDVH9RhRRN7flpcUOPyps4fxrzeonyi8+RF+PXPlN
>   g8iTKMWfXS3upWjzaAfgFx/44RRLlKC3adzljr6hmPLjnCVkXQ5RgjvPnfcCuMuO
>   BOFlS7cgP8g68n9w1mKfsCacNcGjPYQPdL1/1XgnK7Tqzoo8dVA0GtU+CNxB4Tjp
>   w3dqkLI9+nX6V5ZF7nmKBFrnpcsIoD10kLTNM9oVPDpfQC3XgFxUmtBNOB9Nf9I3
>   YZN0djsvMKomSPLa0vuu3sTv0/otr4A0zltoIMUf9cY9IK5NQUf721HGJNwWvxqY
>   uR9qfEjyElBGlEulZwIDAQABoAAwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQADggEBAAVN2aZSJVpg
>   ty9HBAGxP/3rkSEGB2WnmzOdC+bbPYj1UXg+C0TyRyvEtL4r2wvvpt426izWJniG
>   Q8L6SKA5gymzCxSZ7Tn43Ln1pT36TeqXqO+E6JngM4NLV+UDO1V4xzJjA9SKgNjU
>   /sTMqijJz1c3+MZjqzvK3fOjMlTNYmTZADO7Xk4Mmn5S9drA+oNY2gtpzAMrDIEO
>   1sWpSRgOFJGQesxEfuVdQkcj0NPh9pf5Iu48NMWHUlu2ce5FS5u7GQKVDUvopNpo
>   Bf29y05qwUl3OTdHu9pvwN7VYyCIbWrd6YQ0iD6VYDeavh9LB6WVpzvZUDMGUz2e
>   rFOzZ2au/8s= -----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST----- ' at 'certificate'
>   failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression
>   pattern: -{5}BEGIN
>   CERTIFICATE-{5}\u000D?\u000A([A-Za-z0-9/+]{64}\u000D?\u000A)*[A-Za-z0-9/+]{1,64}={0,2}\u000D?\u000A-{5}END
>   CERTIFICATE-{5}(\u000D?\u000A)?.

I have tried all type of combinations to make this work but I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Can we step back just a bit and clarify exactly what you are trying to do?  It looks like you might be trying to create a private certificate authority for use with Amazon Certificate Manager, but you have not clearly indicated what portion of "the AWS site" you are referring to.  More importantly, I have concerns that if you are indeed trying to create a private CA, that this may actually not be what you should be doing to address the original objective that is the reason you are doing whatever you are trying to do, here.  Please clarify that, first.  Private CAs are quite costly.

Comment: Well I'm trying to get a https certificate for a web page that I'm hosting in a EC2 instance. Maybe I'm looking in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1):

try to use syntax

```
file://CSR.pem
```

when specifying a input/output file